# Personalised RSS feed on website

Tags: php, html, mysql, rss, dreamweaver

Can somebody please help me on how i can implement user personalised rss feed on my website.
I am building the website using Dreamweaver, one of the feature i want to include is that when user logs in to their account, they can read their own personalized RSS news feed. User should be able to add their own preferred source for RSS feed when logged in to their account. And i believe i will need somewhere to store links/source for rss feed in mysql database rather than just pasting random rss source link onto the page itself. mysql database will store user details including login information.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! We help you with problems, we don't build an entire application for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

RSS Dreamfeader should get you started - it was a paid product but he's open sourced it - use the license number he's posted next to the download link.

http://www.rnsoft.com/index.php

Tutorials
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/xml/article.php/3698976

http://webdesign.about.com/od/dreamweaverhowtos/ss/dwrss.htm

Comment: thanks for your help. this might just be the solution.